# Copy text from a CMD window executed through a C# windows form

Tags: c#, .net, windows, cmd, clipboard

I created a windows form application that runs a ping command when a button is pressed. Is there any way that I could copy the output from the CMD window to the clipboard?

This is what I am using to run the CMD process:

```
Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
//startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = pingData;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

P.S. The line to hide the CMD window is commented so I can see the window for debugging purposes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the following simple solution:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c ping 192.168.1.1"; //or your thing
p.Start();

p.WaitForExit();
string result = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(result);
```

Comment: As raja says, please dont forget the process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; and read the mentioned article. :) I come tomorrow for further help if needed :)

Comment: No, I have not resolved the issue. I am still receiving this error: "{"StandardOut has not been redirected or the process hasn't started yet."}" from this line in the code: "string allText = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();".

Comment: This code needs to be before the proc.Start. Check the edited code.

Comment: When using the code you edited above I am still being thrown this error: "{"StandardOut has not been redirected or the process hasn't started yet."}".

RedirectStandardOutput is set to true and I am declaring the string "Output" before starting the process.

Comment: It looks like the error that is being thrown is telling me to declare "output" after starting the process. I can't be that "StandardOut has not be redirected" because it is being redirected.

Comment: Maybe the new one? :) I keep trying :)

Comment: Yeah I keep trying too. I implemented "process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;" earlier and it did not work. Also, I just copied the code you reposted and it threw the same error.

Comment: The problem was you added the start info with variable. Dont ask why is wrong. I dont know. What I know, use the start info explicit. :)

Comment: So I can't set the argument to a variable?

Answer (score -1):

you may want to do it in 2 steps

1. process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
   string allText = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
2. System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(allText);  // i think

Comment: don't forget to set the RedirectStandardOutput to true.

Comment: When I apply this to my Application I receive the following:
{"StandardOut has not been redirected or the process hasn't started yet."} 
What is causing this?